# How can I rotate a camera and a model together?

Tags: xna, xna-4.0

I've tried a way of rotating them together. I've tried to add them at the same position and adding them a rotation but they have different axes of rotation. If anyone knows better xna and find a solution please tell me. This is my code:

my camera

```
// Get the new keyboard and mouse state
        MouseState mouseState = Mouse.GetState();
        KeyboardState keyState = Keyboard.GetState();
        // Determine how much the camera should turn
        float deltaX = (float)lastMouseState.X - (float)mouseState.X;
        float deltaY = (float)lastMouseState.Y - (float)mouseState.Y;
        // Rotate the camera
        ((FreeCamera)camera).Rotate(deltaX * .003f, deltaY * .003f);
        Vector3 translation = Vector3.Zero;
        // Determine in which direction to move the camera
        if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.W)) translation += Vector3.Forward;
        if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.S)) translation += Vector3.Backward;
        if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.A)) translation += Vector3.Left;
        if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.D)) translation += Vector3.Right;
        // Move 3 units per millisecond, independent of frame rate
        translation *= 4 * (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.
        TotalMilliseconds;
        // Move the camera
        ((FreeCamera)camera).Move(translation);
        // Update the camera
        camera.Update();
        // Update the mouse state
        lastMouseState = mouseState;
```

my model class

```
class CModel
{
    public Vector3 Position { get; set; }
    public Vector3 Rotation { get; set; }
    public Vector3 Scale { get; set; }

    public Model Model {get; private set;}
    private Matrix[] modelTransforms;   
    private GraphicsDevice graphicsDevice;
    private BoundingSphere boundingSphere;

    public CModel(Model Model, Vector3 Position, Vector3 Rotation, Vector3 Scale, GraphicsDevice graphicsDevice)
    {
        this.Model = Model;

        modelTransforms = new Matrix[Model.Bones.Count];
        Model.CopyAbsoluteBoneTransformsTo(modelTransforms);

        buildBoundingSphere();

        this.Position = Position;
        this.Rotation = Rotation;
        this.Scale = Scale;

        this.graphicsDevice = graphicsDevice;
    } 

public void Draw(Matrix View, Matrix Projection)
    {
        // Calculate the base transformation by combining
        // translation, rotation, and scaling
        Matrix baseWorld = Matrix.CreateScale(Scale) * Matrix.CreateFromYawPitchRoll(Rotation.X, Rotation.Y, Rotation.Z) * Matrix.CreateTranslation(Position);

        foreach (ModelMesh mesh in Model.Meshes)
        {
            Matrix localWorld = modelTransforms[mesh.ParentBone.Index] * baseWorld;

            foreach (ModelMeshPart meshPart in mesh.MeshParts)
            {
                BasicEffect effect = (BasicEffect)meshPart.Effect;

                effect.World = localWorld;
                effect.View = View;
                effect.Projection = Projection;

                effect.EnableDefaultLighting();
            }

            mesh.Draw();
        }
```

Comment: You may want to go to gamedev.stackexchange.com with this question

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the camera is part of the model class and then update the camera with the players position.

Answer (score 0):

Try Microsoft example of a [Chase camera](http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/chasecamera) which will follow your model and rotate with it.